# Can not fill a double array with function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

At the third line I get "Expected a declaration" for instr[0xB8][256]

```
void funcB8 ();
void (*instr[256][257])();
instr[0xB8][256] = &funcB8;
```

Comment: Did you mean to use untyped declarations? Generally you should use complete prototypes in C: `void funcBB(void)`, `void (*inst[X][Y])(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize the array at a specific index outside a function:

```
void (*instr[256][257])() = { [0xB8][256] = &funcB8 };
```

or assign a value to the array, but to do that you have to do that in a function

Comment: Ah, designated member initializers. Nice.

Comment: Have not heard about such syntax before. Should be handy.

Comment: @Alex: It's new in C99. If you're a hard-core traditionalist and only program in C89, you can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

A C program consists of a sequence of *declaration* statements only. Any other statements, including expression statements, are not permitted at the top level. (There is no control flow at the top level. Control starts by calling some function, usually `main`.)

Move the assignment into a *function*:

```
void funcB8();
void (*instr[256][257])();

int main(void)
{
    instr[0xB8][256] = &funcB8;
}
```

Alternatively you can have an initializer in a declaration. For example:

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };    // OK at top level
```

The values in the initializer are constant expressions, and thus they do not require any control flow.

Comment: [Facepalm] Right. I am not in any function currently, thanks :)